# Apache Spark RDD : How to get latest data based on Paired RDD key and value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am reading data from HDFS. I have multiple rows for each user, i have to select the latest row of every user.

Row Example (`RDD [Id: Int, DateTime: String, Name: STRING]`)

```
1,2016-05-01 01:01:01,testa
2,2016-05-02 01:01:01,testb
1,2016-05-05 01:01:01,testa
```

In above example there are two rows where Id=1, but i want every id only once(latest one only and it's corresponding data) i want output RDD like below.

```
2,2016-05-02 01:01:01,testb
1,2016-05-05 01:01:01,testa
```

My Idea

I can collect this data to an array and run for loop to get desired result, by keeping data which is latest for every user.

I read collect gives data to Master node. My data is 30 GB and RAM on Master is 25 GB. So i don't want to try this.

Can you guys share your ideas and code for accomplish this task?

Comment: If you were going to use an array then why bother with Spark ?

Comment: ok that what should be the approach. I am new to apache spark

Comment: And how does `2016-05-01 01:01:01` look like a `Long`?

Comment: Did you encounter any problem in my answer?

Comment: You gave me direction by suggesting to use aggregateByKey, but you answer requires improvement. i will post it's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help someone in need.

```
val yourRdd = sc.parallelize(List(
 (30, ("1122112211111".toLong, "testa", "testa", "testa")),
 (1, ("1122112211111".toLong, "testa", "testa", "testa")),
 (1, ("1122112211119".toLong, "testa", "testa", "testa")),
 (1, ("1122112211112".toLong, "testa", "testa", "testa")),
 (2, ("1122112211111".toLong, "testa", "testa", "testa")),
 (2, ("1122112211110".toLong, "testa", "testa", "testa"))
))

val addToSet1 = (
  s: (Int, (Long, String, String, String)),
  v: ((Long, String, String, String))
) => if (s._2._1 > v._1 ) s else (s._1,v)

val mergePartitionSets1 = (
  s: (Int, (Long, String, String, String)),
  v: (Int, (Long, String, String, String))
) => if (s._2._1 > v._2._1 ) s else v

val ab1 = yourRdd
  .aggregateByKey(initialSet)(addToSet1, mergePartitionSets1)

ab1.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Comment: One major part of contributing at so is to make your code readable with proper formatting. Putting everything in a single line is not always a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your Date-String to a timestamp and aggregate on id by selecting the tuple with most recent timestamp.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDateTime

val yourRdd: RDD[Int, String, String] = sc.parallelize(List(
  1, "2016-05-01 01:01:01", "testa"
  2, "2016-05-02 01:01:01", "testb"
  1, "2016-05-05 01:01:01", "testa"
))

val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");

val zeroVal = ("", Long.MinValue, "", "")

val rddWithTimestamp = yourRdd
  .map({
    case (id, datetimeStr, name) => {
      val timestamp: Long = LocalDateTime.parse(datetimeStr, dateFormetter)
        .toInstant().toEpochMilli()

      (id, (id, timestamp, datetimeStr, name))
    }
  })

val yourRequiredRdd = rddWithTimestamp
  .aggregateByKey(zeroValue)(
    (t1, t2) => if (t1._2 > t2._2) t1 else t2
    (t1, t2) => if (t1._2 > t2._2) t1 else t2
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DataFrame` API:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "2016-05-01 01:01:01", "testA"),
  (2, "2016-05-02 01:01:01", "testB"),
  (1, "2016-05-05 01:01:01", "testA")))
  .toDF("id", "dateTime", "name")

df.withColumn("dateTime", unix_timestamp($"dateTime"))
  .groupBy("id", "name")
  .max("dateTime")
  .withColumnRenamed("max(dateTime)", "dateTime")
  .withColumn("dateTime", from_unixtime($"dateTime"))
  .show()
```

This requires `HiveContext` as your `SQLContext`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```